# i can only login as a guest on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation

I bought a laptop that has Ubuntu 14.04 on it but I only can login as a guest.any idea how to add an administrator or standard account? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always boot into single user mode. See here: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

I would just install a fresh copy of the OS if I were in your shoes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a new user you must be singed in as `root`

If you can sign in then type: `adduser newuser`  "newuser" being the person you wish to add.

If you can not sign in on root or as an administrator I would try to change the ad-min password [See Here.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-and-delete-users-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-vps)  Or [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)